# javascript inside UpdatePanel not working on postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, updatepanel

I have an UpdatePanel containing a table.  I'm calling a javascript function to populate the table data.  Everything works perfectly when the page renders for the first time.  However, when a PostBack occurs the data does not display.  The method DisplaySvcAgmtFeaturesAndOperational is located in a separate .js file. How can I resolve this?

```
<form id="PageForm" runat="server" style="WIDTH: 98%; margin: 1px;">
        <asp:ScriptManager id="scriptManager" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>

...
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="SummaryUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
...

<ItemTemplate>

    <tr>
    <td>
        <% if (!ServiceOrderReadOnly) {%>
             <asp:ImageButton ID="DeleteButton" CommandName="Delete" ImageUrl="~/_imgs/16_l_remove.gif" runat="server" Width="16px" Height="16px" OnClientClick="javascript:return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this resource?');" />
        <%  } %>
    </td>
    <td>
      <%# Eval("serialNumber") %>: <%# Eval("name") %>&nbsp;
    </td>
    <td>
        <script type="text/javascript">
             DisplaySvcAgmtFeaturesAndOperational( <%# Eval("displayServAgmtFeatures")%>, <%# Eval("displayOperationalYesNo")%>, <%#  Eval("operational") %>, <%# Eval("emgCov") %>, <%# Eval("autoExp") %>,<%# Eval("accCov") %>, 
                  <%# Eval("expParts") %>, <%# Eval("wtrCov") %> ) 
         </script>        
    </td>                                       
    </tr>
```